# Применение методов foreach и split в mustache

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, mustache

Пишу приложение, не могу разобраться как вывести значения ArrayList<String< разделенных ";" в mustache ?
Сейчас делаю так, но выводится все вместе с разделителем, а необходимо по отдельности.

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController
{
    @GetMapping("/greeting")

    public String greeting()
    {
        return "greeting";
    }
    @PostMapping("calc")
    public String calc (
            @RequestParam Double sizeCredit,
            @RequestParam Double sizePayment,
            @RequestParam Double creditPeriod,
            @RequestParam Integer paymentType,
            @RequestParam String startDate,
            @RequestParam Double rate,


            Map<String, Object> model )
    {
        Enter enter = new Enter(sizeCredit, sizePayment, creditPeriod, paymentType, startDate, rate);
        List<String> exit = enter.Count();//делает вычисления и кидает значения в лист
        model.put("exit", exit);
        return "calc";
    }

}
```

Мусташ

```
{{#exit}}
        <li>{{.}}</li>
    {{/exit}}
```